# Access another subnet beside wan through router

Tags: routing, router

[image: My network diagram]

I want to access the computer at 192.168.10.5 from my computer ( 192.168.1.2) . I also want to access internet at the same time. If I plug the my computer direct to the switch bypassing my home router , I can access to both by setting two ip addresses on my computer. But when using router , I can't access the 192.168.10.1/24 subnet. Do I need to setup static routing on my router ?

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is VLANs; both the switch and router need to support 802.1Q. That way you divide your network to smaller segments. Traffic between the segments is possible only through a router. You need three VLANs, one for the PC, one for the server and one for the Internet.

On the router:

- VLAN 1 for PC

  - IP address in range 192.168.1.0/24
  - port connecting to the PC an untagged member of this VLAN (access port)
- VLAN 2 for the server

  - IP address in range 192.168.10.0/24
  - port connecting to the switch a tagged member of this VLAN (trunk port)
- VLAN 3 for the Internet

  - IP address in range 10.2.2.0/26
  - port connecting to the switch a tagged member of this VLAN (trunk port)

On the switch:

- VLAN 2 for the server

  - port connecting to the server an untagged member of this VLAN
  - port connecting to the router a tagged member of this VLAN
- VLAN 3 for the Internet

  - port connecting to the Internet an untagged member of this VLAN
  - port connecting to the switch a tagged member of this VLAN

If the router supports 802.1Q, it should be able to route between directly connected VLANs without configuring static routes.

By default a port on the network device can only carry traffic of one VLAN. Tagging is necessary to allow the port to allow traffic from multiple VLANs. VLAN configuration needs to match on the opposing sides of the link - untagged to untagged, tagged to tagged. A regular PC NIC does not support 802.1Q, hence the edge ports are left untagged.

To get the traffic flowing you need to use the router's IP interfaces as default gateways for the server and the PC. The router's default route should point to the Internet. The switch does need IP addresses unless you want to configure them to test connectivity. Router on the other hand must have them on each network - routing between two networks isn't possible if the router does not have an IP interface on both.

---

This is a bit unusual way to connect the devices. More common is to connect the Internet directly to the router:

```
PC ------ SWITCH ------ ROUTER ------ INTERNET
             |
SERVER ------'
```

On the switch:

- VLAN 1 for the PC

  - port connecting to the PC an untagged member of this VLAN
  - port connecting to the router a tagged member of this VLAN
- VLAN 2 for the server

  - port connecting to the server an untagged member of this VLAN
  - port connecting to the router a tagged member of this VLAN

On the router:

- port connecting to the Internet an untagged member of VLAN 3
- port connecting to the switch a tagged member of VLANs 1 and 2
- IP addressing as above

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But can't we do something simpler ? I can't use managed switch here because of cost. Actually I want to run openmeetings on the server and connect other computers to this switch so that they both have access to internet ( different public ip given by isp) and also can video conference with each other.

Comment: Not really. While you can run 2 subnets on one LAN, but it doesn't make really any sense. One VLAN / subnet is the recommended standard practice. That does require a managed switch, but it doesn't need to break the bank - you can get a gigabit 8-port "smart managed" switch for ~$100 nowadays. "Smart managed" switches have web based configuration, and some capabilities available in fully managed devices are missing, but I think that'd fit your needs. But if you do want to run everything on same flat L2 LAN, why don't you just give the server an IP address in 192.168.1.0 -range?